# CiSvc Service not found on Windows Server 2012 while installing CRM 4.0

Tags: installation, dynamics-crm-4

While installing CRM 4.0 on Windows Server 2012, I'm receiving an error: 
Service cisvc was not found on computer 'DVWEB03'.
The specified service does not exist as an installed service

The thing is that on Windows Server 2012 doesn't have a CiSVc service. Unlike Windows Server 2008 & 2003

Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that CRM 4.0 doesn't support Windows Server 2012 - see list [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2669061). Once you'll solve this one you can get few more other issues.

Cicvs is File Indexing Service. I'm not sure if you don't have it installed or it's called different name on Windows Server 2012.

Comment: we ended up abandoning CRM 4.0 install on Windows Server 2013 and went with Windows Server 2008 which worked fine (after a few inevitable CRM install hiccups)